# Pedigree Diagram help

Tags: homework, molecular-genetics, genetics

[image]

I am asked to fill the genotypes in the spaces provided but looks like I am aving a little bit of trouble. can anyone help? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few hints that might help:

Talking about Maria's pedigree:
Firstly, it seems as if you have mixed up with $X^a$ and $X^A$, see that the disorder is X-linked DOMINANT. Anyone with either heterozygous or homozygous dominant expression would have the disease expressed. So the first generation male should have a genotype: $X^aY$, because if it were $X^AY$ then Amelogenesis imperfecta would be expressed as his phenotype and the first generation female should have a homozygous recessive genotype. Also no child in the second generation would suffer from the same. 
(***NOTE***: The one suffering from Amelogenesis in the second generation would have genotype $X^AY$)

As for Gunther disease, both the parent in the first generation should have a *heterozygous* dominant expression and the offspring suffering must have a homozygous recessive expression. And you can apply the same basics in Peter's pedigree.

I think this much should be enough to complete the task, but if you still have some doubt you can put it forward in the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much Shefali for the explanation. I truly appreciate it. Here is my second attempt: http://s837.photobucket.com/user/apothemnew/media/attempt2_zps419409e5.jpg.html?filters[user]=138960233&filters[recent]=1&filters[publicOnly]=1&sort=1&o=0 does it look ok now? Thanks in advance. Sorry for the inconvenience :)

Comment: Well, in the first place I did not understand what does H or h and - indicate?

Comment: @ApothemCyte U have written Gg for peter's father but he could also be GG !

Comment: @Shefali Hello Shefali. Would you please if at all possible be able to help with my new question: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15142/genetic-linkage-mapping-question-help Thank you so much in advance!!